# How to reconstruct R objects without writing them in a file?

Tags: r, object-construction

I have R object which is to be shared with another analyst. I write:

```
dput(objectname,"filename.R")
```

and then the object can be reconstructed by sharing the .R file and using the **dget(*filename*.R)** function.
Now what I want to do is just share the object structure and not the file. Is it possible? 
I tried the following:

```
a <- dput(b)
structure(1:50, .Dim = c(10L, 5L))
```

But cannot reconstruct this object. All I get is :

```
dget(a)
?
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. You want to "reconstruct", which usually means *from file*, but without writing to file?? What is the purpose, what are you trying to do? Reconstruct object from *which* format or state or...?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I wanted to know this because when I want to share an object's structure on this website while asking doubts how will it be possible to reconstruct the object in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> a <- dput(b)
structure(1:50, .Dim = c(10L, 5L))
> a  # 'reconstructing' b
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1   11   21   31   41
 [2,]    2   12   22   32   42
 [3,]    3   13   23   33   43
 [4,]    4   14   24   34   44
 [5,]    5   15   25   35   45
 [6,]    6   16   26   36   46
 [7,]    7   17   27   37   47
 [8,]    8   18   28   38   48
 [9,]    9   19   29   39   49
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50
```

Note that after `dput`ting `b` and assigning it to `a` a message is displayed, to recover b, just print `a`.